# Copy text at line N at point

Tags: copy-paste

How can I make a function that copies text from line number `N` at point?  I will be at some specific line and point position and want to copy the text from a different line `N`.

Answer (score 3):

```lisp
(defun foo (n)
  "Copy line N to the kill-ring.
N is the numeric prefix arg"
  (interactive "p")
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (forward-line (1- n))
    (kill-ring-save (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))))
```

Comment: How would I use it?

Comment: I would like to have a variation where I can pass the line number `N` from the mode-line.

Comment: You say `C-u N M-x foo RET C-y` where N is the desired line number.

Comment: "... from the modeline" - you mean from the minibuffer?

Comment: From minibuffer that you say.

Comment: Then change the `interactive` spec to prompt for a number. That's a trivial change. I answered the question as posed. If you want some specific behavior, you should specify it in your original question - don't "evolve" questions.